# В чем отличия .net core 1.0 и .net core 2.0?

Tags: .net-core, .netcore2.0

Начинаю изучать .net core 1.0, однако, недавно узнал что уже вышла вторая версия платформы. Стоит ли переходить на нее (если ситуация как с angular 1 (js) и angular 2. Может кто работал с обеими версиями платформ и может написать об их ключевых отличиях?

Comment: Я Вас обрадую: уже доступно публичное превью `.NET Core 3.0`. Так что Вы взялись совсем уж за «древнюю» версию :D

Comment: Ну ладно вам) вопрос был задан в сентябре. Тогде еще был шанс))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевые отличия хорошо описаны тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/aspnetcore-2.0

Для изучения используйте ту версию, на которой разбираете примеры. Конфигурация немного отличается.